# What does updated alpha mean in LDA model?

Tags: hyperparameter, topic-model, lda

I'm trying to understand LDA model by reading through implementations of the algorithm.

Many implementations update alpha during training iterations with codes like:

```
psi_sum1 = 0.0e0;
psi_sum2 = 0.0e0;

for (int d = 0; d < doc_size; d++)
{
    psi_sum1 += digamma(float(n_dk[d][k]) + alpha_old[k]) - digamma(alpha[k]);
    psi_sum2 += digamma(float(doc_words[d]) + alpha_sum) - digamma(alpha_sum);
}

alpha[k] = alpha_old[k] * psi_sum1 / psi_sum2;
```

e.g. for 10 topics, the init alpha could be `[1, 1, ..., 1]` (length = 10),
after training, the alpha is updated to `[0.29, 0.30, ..., 0.28]` (length = 10).

What does this updated alpha mean?

Can I use the updated alpha to determine whether the topic number is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

The alpha is a hyperparameter which controls the mixture of topics for any given document. Turn it down and the documents will likely have less of a mixture of topics. Turn it up and the documents will likely have more of a mixture of topics.

> Can I use the updated alpha to determine whether the topic number is
> appropriate?

Tuning it depends upon your problem statement which could be solved with help of domain knowledge.